# Сверстать рамку с градиентом

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такой макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это рамка блока в котором будет текст. Как сверстать такую рамку? Блок будет резиновым и меняться по высоте при ресайзе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.color {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #3eb060, #0cabe1) 1 49%;
  
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="color"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
border-image: 
      linear-gradient(
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
      )
```

По градиенту рекомендую воспользоваться онлайн генераторами градиентов CSS. Коих достаточно в интернете.